# Center bootsrap 3 button toolbar inside div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to center horizontally a bootstrap 3 `btn-toolbar` button inside a `col-lg` div?

```
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-3 noleftpad">
          <div class="well topnestedbut">   
              <div class="btn-toolbar nested-top">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><strong>This must be centered</strong></button>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

CSS:

```
.btn-toolbar.nested-top{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    text-align:center;
}

.well.topnestedbut{
    padding:35px 10px 10px;
}

.noleftpad{
    padding-left:0px;
}
```

I want that the button be attached to the top of the container div, and also centered:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I did:

When an element is positioned absolute it is floating above the content. In this state it will only take up as much room as the content inside of it.

If you set width 100% on that element it will take up 100% of the parent (or relative) containers width.

http://jsfiddle.net/Per3m/3/

```
.btn-toolbar.nested-top{
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
        top:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: The button must be also attached to the top of the container div!

Comment: Yes thank you very much. I'm wondering why `width:100%` has fixed the problem... Please edit your answer so I can validate it according to my update.

Comment: Did my best to explain what's happening. Hope that helps, cheers!